# App Store offer codes flutter implementation

Tags: flutter, xcode, app-store

I made the app store connect settings in the App Store offer codes section and what I want is this;

The user will enter the offer code into the input and I will send it to the app store and start the subscription.

Can I do what I want on the client side without a server? If it can be done, how can I do it?

I don't know how to do it on the client side